Why are there no 12V/5A USB PD chargers/batteries?
Any 100W USB PD 3.0 system must support 20V/5A charging. Naively I assumed that therefore they should support 5A at any of the lower voltage rails! But for some unclear reason, I cannot find any PD based system that will output 5A at less than 20V. Here a few examples:

Anker Prime 100W GaN Charger
UGREEN 20000mAh Portable Charger
AmazonBasics Four-Port GaN Wall Charger

This is consistent among all the different brands and form factors I looked at, be they AC adapters, battery banks, or cigarette lighter adapters. What could be the reason for this? If, as a manufacturer, you put in the effort to bulk up and certify your charger to work at 5A, why would you limit that to only 20V?

Anecdotal: USB PD Rev. 1.0 source profiles 2 to 5 included 12 V besides 5 V and 20 V.

What would be the use case here? Obviously the device itself needs a voltage regulator, so even if it wants 12V, why not regulate down from 20V and save some resistive losses?

@Sneftel, 12V is quite a common voltage many devices (LED strips, motors, etc.) If you want to run enough of them, you're going to need more than 3A. Although personally, I had more of a fringe use in mind: running a Starlink Mini, which needs 60W, off of a 12V USB-C to barrel jack cable I own (it's rated for 5A). However, such PD products don't appear to exist!

Right, but you don't want to run 12V at 3A through a USB cable if you can help it. You want to run the equivalent 20V at 1.8A and convert that to 12V on the device itself. That way you reduce resistive losses by 40%. PD isn't designed or meant to allow a USB wall-wart to be a customizable-voltage power supply. It is solely to maximize the power that can be delivered, by maximizing voltage.

@Sneftel, PD might be intended for maximizing the charging of USB devices, but in effect the USB-IF created a standard for making variable power supplies. Why not use them as such? There's no advantage of techno-snobbiness in not allowing it to be used for lowly motors and LEDs. It strikes me as a very odd decision to allow 5A above 20V but not below.

Because that’s not what it’s for. Simple standards tend to be more effective at accomplishing their goals than flexible complicated standards. It also would make things more complicated and annoying for consumers, who would otherwise have to, say, hunt through the detailed specifications of various power supplies on Anazon to find one which supported the additional functionality required by their device.

(The answers you’ve already received go into this aspect of things more articulately than I have.)

In any case, to address your REAL  issue rather than counterfactuals, there are USB-PD-consuming devices with variable voltage output. Buy one.

Re: your 12V/5A use case in prior comment. There are chargers that implement PPS at 3.3-20V at 5A for all voltages, and there are triggers (with memory)  supporting such. So, yes, you can use USB chargers as general DC power supplies. Now with PD3.1 AVS there are supplies and triggers from 15V-36V/5A (and soon up to 48V). I can supply links if there is interest.

@Sneftel But nowadays PD3.1 chargers are being used as programmable DC power supplies, and not only by hobbyists. For example. Framework has laptops that support both 36V/5A and 48V/5A, Dell has a 165W supply with AVS at 15-28V/5.85A, etc.

@BillDubuque: ah, that makes sense. This whole question was sparked because I own a usb-c to barrel jack cable that's marked 12V/5A, and I couldn't for the life of me find any charger that would support that, even the 100W ones. On closer inspection, I see that it's listed as PD 3.1.

@BillDubuque, do all 100W PD 3.1 chargers support 12V/5A, or only some of them? Looking at this Anker 140W Charger specifically advertised as PD 3.1, it still says only 12V/3A.

Generally if 5A is supported at lower voltages it is only done so via PPS, not by the fixed voltages. But some units do support 5A on the fixed range too, e.g. the XY-PDS100 does  5,9,12,15,20V all at 5A, as well as PPS 3.3-21V at 5A, cf. 2nd photo on this Amazon page.

I just tested an XY-PDS100 with a $3 PD3.0 trigger with DC 5.5 barrel out and it does supply all fixed voltages at 5A  (OCP is 5.4A), if you use a cable emarked for 5A (OCP is 3.4A with non-emarked cable).

To find others search Aliexpress for the chip SW3518. Some allow you to configure 3A vs 5A output on various ranges (both fixed and PPS), e.g. 100W, and 300W, and 400W units.

The reason is USB Power Delivery standard. You cannot make a product that is against a standard and the standard does not allow it.
Also, as per the name, it is a standard for delivering power, it is not intended to suit directly for powering random equipment with any arbitrary voltage or current levels - you ask for some power level, it delivers it, and you can do anything you like with the power and convert it up or down to any voltages you want inside your device.
So no device will request e.g. 12V/5A and thus no device needs to provide 12V/5A, there is no standard that allows it.
The standard started at some version and at some point was up to 60W using up to max 3A and up to max 20V and requires the device to consume up to 3A and if it needs more power then it should use higher voltage to reduce current below 3A.
So all devices up to this point will work like this, they cannot request more than 3A at any voltage and the cables are rated to pass only up to 3A and the maximum voltage you can request is 20V for up to 60W of power.
Then a new version of a standard gets defined.
The 20V was extended to 5A to provide up to 100W instead of 60W, but 100W or 5A is only available at 20V, and to overcome the requirement of 3A limit to 5A safely, it requires an e-marked cable so you cannot go to 5A unless your cable has an ID chip which says it is safely built to support 5A, otherwise the cable is the limitation for the whole system to use only 3A through a 3A cable.
And when the standard was expanded beyond 60W, it did not change the behaviour when the power is 60W or less - it's max 3A only.
If what you suggest was possible, to draw 12V at 5A, it is hard to justify why your device would want to draw 60W with 12V and 5A for 60W, because it will require anyway all the devices including the cable to be new enough to support the 5A 100W standard version, while you can already draw 60W at 3A and 20V with the old standard for less losses.
What I am trying to say, if you already have millions of people already using the old 3A standard up to 60W, why change any of that how it works as the USB is already complex for normal people to use.
The most simplest solution is, if your device needs 60W at 12V 5A, you transfer the 60W from any supply like Type-C with 20V and 3A and use a buck converter to bring it down to 12V 5A.

Because the USB PD 3.0 says so...
However, we have moved on passed this specification and now 12V is supported. Supported voltages in USB PD 3.0 was 5V, 9V, 15V, and 20V.
Why specifically was 12V not supported in USB PD 3.0? Good question... Only 20V was reserved for higher wattages in order reduce current handling requirements for cables and connectors. If 12V was required, then that would mean 8.33A would be required to deliver 100W, thus decreasing power quality for said cables and connectors. That's not really ideal for power delivery. Higher amperage would generate more heat, which would make a cable or connector hotter.
Also, if you want a marketing answer: there was not enough demand for 12V to justify supporting it.

That explains the 12V part, but mainly my question was about why 5A isn't available at any voltage below 20V.

@Rafael I think it does explain it just like my answer does.

@Rafael Honestly, I'm trying to remember why we made that decision (I'm part of the USB-IF committee). It was a while back. If I remember correctly, it was pretty much for the same reason: reducing as much power efficiency loss as possible. A smaller voltage with a higher current draw was not the goal to maintain a specific power efficiency, hence 3A. Having 20V in the first place was more for laptop chargers that were trying to transition out of those barrel jack connectors for battery chargers. Consumers (particularly in the EU) were pretty fed up with proprietary chargers.

@Colin, but once 5A is enabled for 20V, why not for 5-15V?

@Rafael As I said: A smaller voltage with a higher current draw was not the goal to maintain a specific power efficiency, hence 3A.

@Colin, I'm just puzzled by the decision to enable 5A at 20V and nowhere else. If you want to encourage (force) devices to use a higher voltage instead of amperage by limiting current to 3A, why does the standard allow for 20V/5A instead of ~30V/3A?

@Rafael You extend a standard one step at a time. You either keep compatibility with older standards or break it. When PD was extended to 100W all your existing infrastructure was 20V 3A already and for example laptops worked at 20V already so 30V would need to redesign the laptop input but keeping 20V and allowing more current is how laptop inputs worked anyway. The battery voltage is irrelevant. The charger inside the laptop converts the input power to suitable voltages and currents for the battery.

@Rafael, 60W delivered as 20V/3A loses less power in the wires than 60W delivered as 12V/5A.  Since 20V/3A was already supported, and 12V/5A is strictly inferior, there's no reason to add it to the standard.

@Mark, 9V/3A is strictly inferior to 20V/1.35A, but it's still enabled under the USB PD standard. Clearly the USB-IF is not so picky when it comes to efficiency. Yet for some reason they allow 20V/5A, but not 12V/5A.

@Rafael The rules for it is based on power in PD 2.0 standard. PD 1.0 is not used any more. You want some power, and figure out what voltage you need so current stays below 3A. And if you go above 3A, you need 5A capable cables, which means those marketed as 100W, even if you want to transfer 60W at 5A 12V or 25W at 5V 5A. It makes no sense to require consumers to use special 5A cables when transferring up to and including 60W. PD is a standard for power delivery, not a standard for universal programmable power supply (which actually the PD 3.0 does have).

@Rafael I'm starting to suspect that your concern is more about market availability than feasibility. It's not taboo to make 12V/5A, it's just simply not compliment for industry standards. Industry standards are built upon demand from our customers. The USB-IF committee is a huge conglomerate of company like Apple, HP, Dell, etc. that all come together, on a voluntary basis might I add, and discuss a common ground based on customer needs. You're welcome to make your own device, just don't expect a USB certified sticker on it.

@Colin, my question wasn't a product request. I still don't understand what gain there was to not making 12V/5A part of the USB standard. I don't see any gain in disallowing a feature that people who want it will use, and those who don't will never hear about it.

@Rafael We can go back and forth on how unfair it is, and I may agree with you. I'm just letting you know that there's barely any demand for it. You can try to argue that people want it, and I will just say that there's not enough people. We have the marketing resources to prove it. It's like when you try to get support from a supplier: if you buy 10 of their products rather than 10000, do you really expect them to dedicate their time and resources to support you to your expectations? The number of 12V/5A devices is greatly outnumbered by 12V/3A devices.

That still doesn't explain it. I perfectly understand why a manufacturer might make a 20V/3A charger rather than a 12V/5A charger. What I don't understand is, why make a 20V/5A charger and then disable 12V/5A? It's doing 5A anyways. It doesn't take more time or resources, it's just a setting in the microcontroller! Typically if a company can increase their user base for completely free, even if only by a small amount, they'll do it.

As other have mentioned, the answer to the headline question of "why aren't there any 12V/5A chargers?" is "the standard".
But there's another question in the body which is "why aren't there any 5A chargers at less than 20V?". And the answer is that there are. These are typically high powered chargers that support PPS (this Belkin charger claims to offer "5V – 21V / 4.75A / 100W Max" in PPS mode for example). The standard allows this, but only for voltages above 15V. If you have an X Watt charger, it is permitted to offer X / 20 Amps of current at any voltage between 15 and 20. So a 100W charger could offer 15V 5A, or an 80W charger could offer 15V 4A.

As I mentioned yesterday in comments on the question, there are also chargers that go up to 5A on the fixed voltage ranges too (vs. only on PPS as above).

To clarify, when you say 'the standard', do you mean PD to the exclusion of PPS? Meaning that PPS may offer 12V/5A, but not PD 3.0? I'm still unsure if PD supports 5A on the lower voltage ranges or not.

In this case I mean version 1.0 of the USB PD 3.2 specs, retrieved from https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-power-delivery, which I've linked in the answer. So far as I can tell, the specs do not permit alternate fixed voltages over 9V or fixed currents over 3A, so these currents are only accessible in PPS mode.

Could you please give a more precise document location supporting your claim that "the specs do not permit ..."

@BillDubuque This is based on section 10.2.3.1 of the linked USB PD 3.2 (v1.0) standard.
